# Realtime logging with capybara and chrome browser

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver

It seems that chrome brwoser have capability to log everything to the bash console while running with chromedriver and capybara.

How can we stream that log real time while running test using capybara (perhaps with cucumber test runner)? The log should include network request + info/warn/error that get logged in the chrome console window.